# How to Create a Dependent Drop-Down List in Excel Using C#

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller

I have two dependent tables..Need to make a dependent ddl in Excel Cells by adding validation using c#.Made Drop Down Cell, but Please help to make Product Cell cascade or dependent cell based on Provider Cell value.

```
worksheet.DataValidations.Add(new DataValidation(worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("L" + i.ToString(), "L" + i.ToString()))
{
    Type = DataValidationType.List,
    Operator = DataValidationOperator.Between,
    Formula1 = RangeProviders,
    InputMessageTitle = "Provider",
    InputMessage = "Please select a Provider",
    ErrorTitle = "Invalid Provider",
    ErrorMessage = "Provider must be one from the list."
});

worksheet.DataValidations.Add(new DataValidation(worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("M" + i.ToString(), "M" + i.ToString()))
{
    Type = DataValidationType.List,
    Operator = DataValidationOperator.Between,
    Formula1 = RangeProducts,
    InputMessageTitle = "Product",
    InputMessage = "Please select a Product",
    ErrorTitle = "Invalid Product",
    ErrorMessage = "Product must be one from the list."
});
```